# C++: Alternative to the CHtmlVIew to show PDF/HTML files in MFC based application

Tags: c++, mfc

Are the any alternatives how to display PDF/HTML file in the MFC based application without using ActiveX elements like `CHtmlView`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative would be [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). It uses the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser engine, unlike `CHtmlView` that's based on IE.

If the reason you are looking for an alternative is, that you need a more up-to-date browser implementation, then WebView2 delivers. If, on the other hand, you are looking for an alternative, that's easier to use, then not a whole lot changes. Either one expects very intimate familiarity with COM and C++.

Comment: At the moment I have hand to hold off on rolling out WebView2 in my app because there is too many lacking features sadly. I have the nuts and bolts in place to use it which is good but loose too much functionality at this stage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Do you know wether WebView2 is an ActiveX component or not?

Comment: It is not an ActiveX control (though you could probably try to wrap it up in one).

Comment: ====
Thanks.
====